# Find a list of text and replace at matching fields

Tags: python, unix, replace

All right I accept that the title is vague for my problem and I am not able to put it in a more comprehensible manner. I am new to programming and my technical jargon is still developing.

I have two files, file `A` looks like:

```
CHROM   POS ID  AGM12   AGM14   AGM15   AGM18 ..
1   14930   rs150145850     0/0 1/1 0/0  0/0 ..
1   14933   rs138566748 0/0 0/0 0/0  0/0 ..
1   63671   rs116440577 0/1 0/0 0/0  0/0 ..
2   808922  rs6594027   0/0 0/0 0/0  0/1 ..
2   753474  rs2073814   1/0 0/0 0/1  0/0 ..
3   753405  rs61770173  0/0 1/1 0/0  1/0 ..
...
...
...
```

File `B` looks like:

```
CHROM   POS rsID    Sample_ID
1   14930   rs150145850 AGM15
2   808922  rs6594027   AGM18
3   753405  rs61770173  AGM12
...
...
...
```

I am looking to use POS field information (column 2) in File `B` to replace the content in the corresponding `Sample_ID` in File `A` by `NA`.

For example: the output should look like

```
CHROM   POS ID  AGM12   AGM14   AGM15   AGM18
1   14930   rs150145850     0/0 1/1 NA   0/0
1   14933   rs138566748 0/0 0/0 0/0  0/0
1   63671   rs116440577 0/1 0/0 0/0  0/0
2   808922  rs6594027   0/0 0/0 0/0  NA
2   753474  rs2073814   1/0 0/0 0/1  0/0
3   753405  rs61770173  NA  1/1 0/0  1/0
```

How could I do this in Python or Unix?

Comment: just to be clear, you have 2 files. the files are lines of data. the data in both files match via the "POS" key. and you want to replace the contents of the colm listed in file2 in file1 into NA ? - also, can there be duplicates of the same key in file2?

Comment: Hard to tell how the columns are separated, I'd say tab separated but for the first data row of file `A`.

Comment: It looks like the columns are tab delimited? Is SO doing something to turn that tab into spaces? Really, my question is, how to you define the output alignment?

Comment: @InbarRose since you mentioned duplicates, i forgot to mention that File A can also have duplicates at "POs' key but the corresponding variable in CHROM could be different. For e.g.:                    CHROM   POS ID  AGM12   AGM14   AGM15   AGM18 ..
1   14930   rs150145850     0/0 1/1 0/0  0/0 ..
1   14933   rs138566748 0/0 0/0 0/0  0/0 ..
1   63671   rs116440577 0/1 0/0 0/0  0/0 ..
2   14930   rs1578634   0/0 1/1 0/0  0/0 ..                           2   808922  rs6594027   0/0 0/0 0/0  0/1 ..
2   753474  rs2073814   1/0 0/0 0/1  0/0 ..
3   753405  rs61770173  0/0 1/1 0/0  1/0 ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that uses the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module (I'm assuming that your columns are tab delimited).

```
import csv
import collections

a = 'path/to/a'
b = 'path/to/b'
output = 'output/path'

pos = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open(b) as csvin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvin, delimiter='\t')
    for line in reader:
        pos[line['POS']].append(line['Sample_ID'])

with open(a) as csvin, open(output, 'wb') as csvout:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvin, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvout, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in reader:
        fields = pos.get(line['POS'], [])
        for field in fields:
            line[field] = 'NA'
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one out.

```
def method(file1, file2, fileout):
    d1, d2, headers = {}
    i = 1
    with open(file1) as f1:  
        for line in f1:
            vars = line.split('\t') #i am assuming tab seperated
            d1[vars[1]] = [vars[0]] + vars[2:]
    with open(file2) as f2:
        for line in f2:
            vars = line.split('\t')
            d2[vars[1]] = vars[2]
    for header in d1['POS']:
        headers[header] = i
        i+=1
    with open(fileout, 'w') as fo:
        fo.write("%s\tPOS\t%s\n" % (d1['POS'][0], "\t".join(d1['POS'][1:]))
        del d1['POS']         
        for key, values in d1.items():
            if key in d2:
                d1[key][headers[d2[key]]] = "NA"
            fo.write("%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (values[0], key, "\t".join(values[1:])))
```

Comment: It probably makes sense to use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for this.

Comment: yes, but i like writing answers that use the least amount of imports as possible, especially when beginners are involved.

Comment: fair enough. I suppose though it's a useful point to know that there is a (batteries included) module to do most of the annoying bits of this. There are quite a few pitfalls in handling csv files (whitespace, quoted values etc)

Comment: @InbarRose -1 no, not "fair enough" -- beginners should be taught always to use the "batteries-included" libraries!

Comment: @katrielalex beginners imho should learn to understand how something works before outsourcing it. also, difference of philosophy does not make my answer less correct, and it feels quite childish to me that you would down-vote a correct answer because you dont agree that it is the right method to use, instead, write your own answer, and simply dont upvote mine.

Comment: @InbarRose The point of SO is to teach people to write good code. Your answer is _bad code_. (It has value as an example of how some of the `csv` functionality might work, but it's never the right way to read a TSV file.)

Comment: @katrielalex again - different philosophies, not everyone has to agree with you. i personally, do not agree with you on this. now, if there is anything further to discuss about THIS then please do, otherwise, lets continue in a chat.

Comment: @InbarRose since you mentioned duplicates, i forgot to mention that File A can also have duplicates at "POs' key but the corresponding variable in CHROM could be different. For e.g.:                    CHROM   POS ID  AGM12   AGM14   AGM15   AGM18 ..
1   14930   rs150145850     0/0 1/1 0/0  0/0 ..
...
2   14930   rs1578634   0/0 1/1 0/0  0/0 ..                           2   808922  rs6594027   0/0 0/0 0/0  0/1 ..                              I want to replace the data point at the intersection of the matched POS/and CHROM key with the Sample_ID in File 1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing some packages, you can do this really neatly with `pandas`:

```
A = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv("A.txt", sep="\t", index_col=(0,1))
B = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv("B.txt", sep="\t", index_col=(0,1))

A.join(B) # the resulting dataset
```

Of course, you'll have to pick up `pandas` to do this.

Comment: this will not solve his problem, he is not merging data, he is replacing data in columns with NA where the colum for the data key is in the second file.

Comment: @InbarRose good point -- `A.join(B, how="outer")` will do that.